# javascript | Click Event | Declare in different ways

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Please see code snippet. It has nothing to do with throttle concept.

I declare click event like `btn.addEventListener("click", outerFunction);`. It gets invoked but the statement 'console.log("button is clicked outer function " + e.pointerType)' does not get executed.

While if I declare function inline then it works as expected.

So i am not able to understand why it does not work when it is declared in `outerfunction`

```
const btn = document.querySelector("#throttle");
const btn2=document.querySelector("#newthrottle");

// Throttling Function
const throttleFunction = (func, delay) => {
  // Previously called time of the function
  let prev = 0;
  return (...args) => {
    // Current called time of the function
    let now = new Date().getTime();

    // Logging the difference between previously
    // called and current called timings
    console.log(now - prev, delay);

    // If difference is greater than delay call
    // the function again.
    if (now - prev > delay) {
      prev = now;

      // "..." is the spread operator here
      // returning the function with the
      // array of arguments
      
      //debugging arguments
      var inputArguments = [...args]
      console.log("arguments" + inputArguments);
      return func(...args);
    }
  };
};

function outerFunction(e) {
  console.log('Outer function')
    throttleFunction(((e)=>{
        console.log("button is clicked outer function " + e.pointerType)
    }),1500)
    
}

//this does not work
btn.addEventListener("click", outerFunction);

//this works like a charm
btn.addEventListener("click", throttleFunction((event)=>{
    console.log("button is clicked throttle " + event.pointerType)
    }, 1500));


function onButtonClick(e){
  console.log('Hello World onbutton Click' + e);
}

btn2.addEventListener("click", onButtonClick);
```

Comment: Scope. The PASSED event is not available to the throttle function - you need a closure

Comment: mplungjan, can you please add closure and show me.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can do something like this -

```
function outerFunction(e) {
   console.log('Outer function')
   const t = throttleFunction((e)=>{
        console.log("button is clicked outer function " + e.pointerType)
   },1500);
   t();
}
```

But it will be undefined so instead of returning an anonymous function try calling the callback function.

Comment: I tried but no luck